# How to wrap a property with AsyncPipe by default in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, redux

I'm using Angular2 + ng2-redux, and end up writing lots of `{{(myProperty | async).something}}` in every template, which is annoying.

Is there a way to set a property which is already wrapped by AsyncPipe itself and let the templates stay clean?